# Access dict values by function parameter

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to write a function `replace(d, v, e)` where `d` is a `dict` and `v` and `e` are `int`s.  The function is supposed to replace all dictionary values of `v` to `e`.

This code works fine:

```py
def replace(d, v, e):
    for key, value in d.items():
        if value == v:
            d[key] = e
    return d 

print(replace({1:2, 3:4, 4:2}, 2, 7)) # output: {1: 7, 3: 4, 4: 7}
```

But when I alter the code to change the value using `d.values()`, it doesn't work:

```py
def replace(d, v, e):
    for i in d.values():
        if i == v:
            i = e
    return d 
    
print(replace({1:2, 3:4, 4:2}, 2, 7)) # output: {1: 2, 3: 4, 4: 2}
```

May I have any advice on how to modify the 2nd code to make it work like the 1st code?

Comment: You can't. The assignment to `i` only changes the symbol `i` it doesn't effect the dictionary. Stick to the first version.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the second code "to work" would require using `items` in place of `values`, so in short, **you cannot modify the value without knowing the key.** What your second code does is only to assign the value to `i` locally in the function without ever affecting the dictionary.

Another remark, your first version of the function modifies the dictionary in place and returns it, which is not a really good practice, you should do either the one or the other.

Finally, here is a version to return a new dictionary without changing the input, using a dictionary comprehension:

```
def replace(d, v, e):
    return {k: e if val==v else val for k,val in d.items()}

replace({1: 2, 3: 4, 4: 2}, 2, 7)
# {1: 7, 3: 4, 4: 7}
```